# how to map Linux (CentOS) drive to Mac (Snow Leopard)?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, mac

Anyone know how to map a Linux (CentOS 6.2) drive to a Mac (Snow Leopard)? I have root privileges. The Linux machine is not in a local network, but accessed via the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about other people, but [sshfs](http://www.turingtarpit.com/2009/04/mounting-remote-filesystems-on-osx-leopard-using-sshfs-macfuse-and-macfusion/) works fine for me. Alternatively, you could set up a VPN and then do a samba mount, which is cumbersome but works.

Or better yet, you could do a [nfs mount](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/mac/mounting-nfs-volumes-in-os-x/430), which is about as simple as you can get.

Comment: Thanks qweet. Looks like the link you provided states it's only valid for Leopard. Curious though. Did you go through the whole process in the link, or could possibly I just use sshfs alone somehow to keep things much simpler?

Comment: What do you mean by simpler?  You install SSHFS, and its the prerequisites, then you connect.

Comment: By simpler I mean, do I need to install MacFuse and Macfusion (or equivalent; sounds like "yes")? Regarding the nfs mount link, this looks simpler, but there's no mention of logging in anywhere to the server. Should the Mac user enter username and password to access the server somewhere in this process?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the native AFP protocol to share with the Apple, use `netatalk`:

```
$ yum info netatalk
Available Packages
Name        : netatalk
Arch        : i686
Epoch       : 4
Version     : 2.2.0
Release     : 2.el6
Size        : 694 k
Repo        : epel
Summary     : AppleTalk networking programs
URL         : http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : This package enables Linux to talk to Macintosh computers via the
            : AppleTalk networking protocol. It includes a daemon to allow Linux
            : to act as a file server over EtherTalk or IP for Mac's.
```

It's in the EPEL repos.

Since the other box is somewhere on the Internet, you can can use OpenVPN to set up a connection between the two.  If the Linux box is the OpenVPN server, TunnelBlick works very well as an OpenVPN client on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

**iSCSI** is another possible solution for your problem.

While the iSCSI-target is freely available on CentOS, you probably have to buy a iSCSI-inittiator solution for MAC. At least I found some hits with reports about working commercial iSCSI-initiators for Snow Leopard.